# line break aware custom environment

Tags: environments, line-breaking

I have a use-case where I would like to specify some special formatting for the text being input via the `\input` command. This text is customer's address being printed in some sort of a form. Ideally the input file should not contain any TeX commands and be aware of line breaks.

So if the input file is:

```
John Doe
Some Street X
ZIP City
```

the LaTeX template contains:

```
 \begin{customer}
   \input{customer}
 \end{customer}
```

I know how to create a new environment, but how can I preserve line breaks from the `customer.tex`. I don't want the `.tex` file to contain `\\` for the line breaks. Verbatim environment does not fit well here since it uses an own font and formatting.

P.S.:
A short note: `verbatim` environment does not work, since it does not preserve the formatting from the customer environment. I need to merge the ability of line breaks into my customer environment. E.g. customer environment can cause the text to be formatted as `{\large \textsc{...}}`, or whatever else.

Comment: Can the file to be input contain empty lines?

Comment: Yes, why not. It is up to the content provider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That syntax is redundant: something like `\custinput{customer}` might be better; let's try:

```
\newcommand{\custinput}[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\obeylines
  \input{#1}\endgroup}

\custinput{customer}
```

LaTeX borrows the macro `\obeylines` from `plain.tex`: its definition is

```
\def\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active\let^^M\par}
```

Saying `\catcode\endlinechar\active` could be safer, but it's not very common that the end-of-line character is different from the default one. Such a command should be issued inside a group, because otherwise its effect will last "forever". In this group the active end-of-line is defined to be equivalent to `\par`.

A bit of theory: TeX appends a character to each line it reads after disposing of the operating system end-of-record signal. This is because every operating system has its own ideas of how a record should end; some use a combination `<CR><LF>`, others only `<LF>`, others only `<CR>` (`<CR>` is ASCII 13, `<LF>` is ASCII 10). Others don't use any character at all, because their records have fixed length and the record is padded by ASCII `<NUL>` characters or even spaces.

The default end-of-line character appended by TeX is `<CR>`, but it depends on the value of the integer parameter `\endlinechar` (whose initial value is 13). If this value is negative, no end-of-line character is inserted: this is sometimes useful in applications. The category code of this character is usually 5, which means that two such characters in succession are converted to `\par` (spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored), otherwise it's converted to a space. From this follows the property that a blank line ends a paragraph.

Setting the category code of this character `\active` (that is, 13) allows us to define it to be anything we want; we'll use the default meaning, that is `\par`, which will do what's intended. A convenient way to refer to ASCII 13 as a character is `^^M`. However we couldn't say

```
\newcommand{\custinput}[1]{\begingroup
   \catcode`^^M=\active \def^^M{something}%
   \input{#1}\endgroup}
```

because at the moment of the definition the category code of `^^M` is *not* 13. Indeed the real definition of `\obeylines` is

```
{\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with %
 \gdef\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let^^M\par}%
 \global\let^^M\par} % this is in case ^^M appears in a \write
```

and this shows why using `\obeylines` in the definition is "more elegant".

Answer (score 3):

In the `customer` environment you can change the category code of `\endlinechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{customer}
  {\setlength\parindent{0pt}\catcode\endlinechar13}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{customer}
\input{file}
\end{customer}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Gonzalo, hello! This is also a possible solution and I gave you a +1 vote, but egregs solution is more elegant ;)

Comment: @ovanes: they are actually almost the same. However Gonzalo's relies on a definition of the active end-of-line that's not guaranteed. @Gonzalo: it's not necessary to reset the catcode of the end-of-line.

Comment: @egreg: you're right. I'll update my answer. Thanks.